# Selenium Grid (Java) does not work correctly with new Windows Terminal

Tags: java, selenium, windows-terminal

We are using in our project Selenium (Java) for testing and we have Selenium Grid (basically a hub with various browsers) successfully running.

The script for running Selenium Grid for Windows CLI is this one, stored in a .bat file:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 4546
start java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 4547
```

This script is working all the time, but it ones 3 separate windows in windows, making a bit clunky.

Recently, Windows has released a Windows Terminal (WT) - and one of its new features is option to run several tabs in only one window. Therefore, I have rewritten the former script to one utilizing Windows Terminal so my taskbar wouldn´t be cluttered, and it looks like this:

`wt -d d:\Programs\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub; sp -d d:\Programs\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver='D:\drivers\chromedriver.exe' -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 4546; sp -H -d d:\Programs\HIE\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver='D:\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe' -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 4547`

Problem is, that whenever I run this WT script instead of the former one, it works only every second time.
Before you gonna ask, yes, I checked with notepad++ for differences in letters or possible unwanted spaces after transcribing, human errors - the script itself is fine.

The former script works every time (every time the browser is launched and our test(s) completed correctly), this one works every second (even) time, every first one (odd) it leaves an error message in our IntteliJ console:

Can somebody help me with this one? I have no idea what might be wrong.

```
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-B4ED459', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 185 milliseconds
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at com.browsersoft.selenium.core.SeleniumRunner.run(SeleniumRunner.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1260)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:814)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at com.browsersoft.selenium.SeleniumManager.executeTest(SeleniumManager.java:42)
    at com.browsersoft.config.core.scenario.Scenario.executeSeleniumStep(Scenario.java:223)
    at com.browsersoft.config.core.scenario.Scenario.executeStep(Scenario.java:189)
    at com.browsersoft.config.gui.document.scenario.ScenarioStepPanel$4.run(ScenarioStepPanel.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-B4ED459', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-B4ED459', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory.lambda$get$0(ServicedSession.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12(ActiveSessionFactory.java:180)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply(ActiveSessionFactory.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2(NewSessionPipeline.java:66)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4747)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3(NewSessionPipeline.java:69)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(DistinctOps.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Streams.java:397)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:720)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This is the contents of WT console windows after the unsuccessful run:

```
16:09:30.589 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2021-10-21 16:09:30.985:INFO::main: Logging initialized @744ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:09:31.670 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
16:09:31.672 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://172.30.1.4:4444/grid/register/
16:09:31.673 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://172.30.1.4:4444/wd/hub
16:09:32.615 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://172.30.1.4:4546
16:09:32.616 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://172.30.1.4:4547
16:10:32.120 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}, version: }
16:10:32.124 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=63e678db-5111-42b8-ba59-bb9780f21e47, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platformName=WIN10, platform=WIN10}
```

```
16:09:30.653 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 4546
2021-10-21 16:09:31.510:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1210ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:09:31.721 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
16:09:31.800 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4546
16:09:31.801 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
16:09:32.082 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
16:09:32.341 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
16:09:32.616 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
16:10:32.191 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
    ],
    "extensions": [
    ]
  },
  "version": ""
}
16:10:32.193 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

```
16:09:30.704 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 4547
2021-10-21 16:09:31.577:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1216ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:09:31.780 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
16:09:31.862 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4547
16:09:31.862 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
16:09:32.135 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
16:09:32.340 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
16:09:32.616 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what was wrong and I am posting the answer in case somebody else had similar problems:

It turns out there was nothing wrong with Selenium or Windows Terminal, we had to start using the latest stable release of Selenium Grid (we were still using 3.x.x version because it was  the only one supported for a long time and only recently they released 4.x.x version) + change the scripts, because Selenium developers decided to change the switches in between versions, so the old scripts (posted in the question itself) will not work, and had to be updated like this:

```
@echo off
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar hub
start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar node --hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register --port 4546
start java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar node --hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register --port 4547
```

and similarly for Windows Terminal:

```
wt -d d:\Programs\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar hub; sp -d d:\Programs\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar node --hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register --port 4546; sp -H -d d:\Programs\SeleniumStandaloneServer\ java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\Praca\Automation\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.1.1.jar node --hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register --port 4547
```

Now the Grid is working correctly with both of those scripts.